# iOS popToRootViewControllerAnimated not working on delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I've implemented a custom delegate method which should pop the root view controller if some data arrives from server. 
By clicking the back button in child controller 1st method `back()` checks if any changes were made in text fields and shows an UIActionSheet in case there are some changes.

**1.**

```
func back() {
        if modified {
            let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: NSLocalizedString("SAVESETTINGS", comment: "Settings were changed. Do you want to save them?"), delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "No", destructiveButtonTitle: "Yes")
            actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = .Default
            actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
        }
        else {
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
```

The ActionSheet delegate method sends the data and the controller is waiting for the answer
**2.**

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if buttonIndex == 0 {
        self.socket.send(someData, tag: someTag)
    }
    else {
       self.modified = false
       self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }     
}
```

The delegate method checks if the right answer is here and should pop the root view controller.

**3.**

```
func ackReceived(tag: Int32) {
    if tag == someTag {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

The root view controller pops in 1st and 2nd method if there are no changes or if the 2nd button is pressed in UIActionSheet, but it is not working in 3d method.

All methods are called. I end up by

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I also checked the debugger, the navigation controller is not `nil`.

I hope you can help me with this problem. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is self in the 3rd example? Add an `NSLog(@"%@",self)`

Comment: these 3 methods are in the same controller.

Comment: I don't care where they are, I want to know what you see in the log. (Sorry, didn't mean to be harsh).

Comment: Log shows the same controller I'm in.

Comment: Did you add NSLog(@"%@",self) to be beginning of each method? If so, please copy-paste the output here. Why are you trying so hard to avoid posting the console log?

Comment: `2015-03-20 14:01:03.822 Control[1942:424934] <Control.DateTimeSettingsViewController: 0x13f637cc0>

2015-03-20 14:01:04.667 Control[1942:424934] <Control.DateTimeSettingsViewController: 0x13f637cc0>

2015-03-20 14:01:04.802 Control[1942:424984] <Control.DateTimeSettingsViewController: 0x13f637cc0>`

Comment: More importantly, which thread is `ackReceived` called on - describe how it is called...

Comment: Wain, thank you for this hint! It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank the hint from Wain, I've found the issue. `func ackReceived(tag: Int32) {}` wasn't called in the main queue.
UI as UIKit methods are not thread safe and should be called in the main queue.

```
func ackReceived(tag: Int32) {
    if tag == someTag {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                return
            })
    }
}
```

is the right way to call UI methods.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

not work because your nav is nil. you can check it by for example print("mainIconTapped: " + String(self.navigationController));